# Putting anything in front of \item in lists

Tags: itemize

So for example if I have this list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

   \begin{itemize}
    \item one
    \clap{some text}\item two 
    \item three
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

It would compile like this:

[image]

where `some text` is rendered in place of a first bullet, but I want it to be where I marked it with the arrow. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

   \begin{itemize}
    \item one
    \item \makebox[0pt][r]{some text\hspace{0.5cm}}two
    \item three
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nice and easy :) I allowed myself to use your approach and make it safer (by checking for the width of the preceding text in relation to the margin) and abstracted it into a alternate version of the `\item` macro.

Answer (score 21):

Following up on the idea of @UlrikeFischer here is a way how to use it with a smooth user interface, i.e. the syntax is

```
\item[<mark>](<text before label>)
```

Note that *both* arguments are optional:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item[+] two
  \item(text) three
  \item[--](text) four
\end{itemize}
```

Moreover, I added a checker for the width of the text preceding the items label that throws out a warning if the text exceeds the length of one line. Preceding textes that are not too overlong, i.e. two lines, can still be handled by this solution.

[image: showcase]

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@item\item
\def\item{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\item@}{\item@[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\item@[#1]{\kernel@ifnextchar({\item@@[#1]}{\item@@[#1]()}}
\def\item@@[#1](#2){\ltx@item[#1]\itemc@mment{#2}\ignorespaces}
\def\itemc@mment#1{%
  \@tempdima\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+\itemindent+1in\relax
  \setbox0\hbox{\ignorespaces#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\@tempdima
    \@latex@warning{Overfull item comment
      (\the\dimexpr\wd0-\@tempdima\relax)}\fi
  \ifdim\wd0>\z@
    \hspace{-.67em}
    \makebox[\z@][r]{%
      \smash{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\@tempdima-.175cm\relax}{%
        \setlength\parindent\z@
        \addtolength\baselineskip{-.33em}
        \ifdim\wd0<\@tempdima\hspace{0pt plus 1fill}\fi#1}}
      \hspace{.175cm}
    }
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item[+] two
  \item(text) three
  \item[--](text) four
  \item(text text text text text text text) five
  \item six
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength\itemindent{-1in}
  \item one
  \item[+] two
  \item(text) three
  \item[--](text) four
  \item(text text text text text text text) five
  \item six
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

### Addendum

Note that this solution supports nested lists too.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item first
    \begin{itemize}
      \item sub one
      \item[:] sub two
      \item(text) sub three
      \item[:](text) sub four
    \end{itemize}
  \item[+] two
  \item(text) three
  \item[--](text) four
  \item(text text text text text text text) five
  \item six
\end{itemize}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: Nice catch there! Perhaps you can add an `\item six` for show?

Comment: @KessVargavind -- thx! and yes, I add an `\item` below to see how it reacts with long prefixes.

Answer (score 9):

If you're only wanting this at the "root" level of an `itemize`, you can use `\textbullet`, otherwise use `\itemmark` (which adapts to the level of `itemize`).

The solution below relies on the fact that you can specify an `\item[<mark>]` by using the optional argument `<mark>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemmark}{\expandafter\csname labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item[some text~1\ \textbullet] two 
  \item[some text~2\ \itemmark] three
  \begin{itemize}
    \item four
    \item[some text~3\ \itemmark] five
  \end{itemize}
  \item six
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I just define `\clap` as

```
\def\clap#1\item{\item[#1~$\bullet$]}
```

Everything else remains unchanged.  The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\clap#1\item{\item[#1~$\bullet$]}
\begin{document}

   \begin{itemize}
    \item one
    \clap{some text}\item two 
    \item three
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To handle itemization depth automatically, one can instead define `\clap` as

```
\def\clap#1\item{\item[#1~\itemmark]}
```

and use Werner's definition of `\itemmark`.